# Redux thunk design for file upload, including cancel and progress

Tags: file-upload, redux, functional-programming, axios, redux-thunk

Wanting to upload some files in react-redux, I got the following idea :

- Set a redux-thunk `uploadFile` action, which initiate the upload, taking a `File` descriptor as parameter
- Define my own "file descriptor" serializable in the store (with a `uuid`, a `pending`, a `sent`, a `errored` and a `pending` properties
- Set some other FSA like `addFile`, `removeFile`, `setFileErrored`, `setFileSent`, `setFileSent`

like so

*reducer*

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case FILES__ADD_FILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        files: [
          ...state.files,
          action.payload
        ]
      }
    case FILES__REMOVE_FILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        files: state.files.filter(
          file => file.id !== action.payload
        )
      }
    case FILES__SET_FILE_ERRORED:
      return {
        ...state,
        files: state.files.map(file => {
          if(file.id !== action.payload.fileId) {
            return file
          }

          return {
            ...file,
            sending: false,
            errored: true,
            sent: false
          }
        })
      }
    case FILES__SET_FILE_SENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        files: state.files.map(file => {
          if(file.id !== action.payload) {
            return file
          }

          return {
            ...file,
            sending: true,
            errored: false,
            sent: false
          }
        })
      }
    case FILES__SET_FILE_SENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        files: state.files.map(file => {
          if(file.id !== action.payload) {
            return file
          }

          return {
            ...file,
            sending: false,
            errored: false,
            sent: true
          }
        })
      }
    case FILES__SET_FILE_PROGRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        files: state.files.map(file => {
          if(file.id !== action.payload.fileId) {
            return file
          }

          return {
            ...file,
            progress: action.payload.progress
          }
        })
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
```

*actions*

```
// skipping static actions

export const uploadFile = (actualFile) => {
  const file = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    sending: false,
    sent: false,
    errored: false
  }

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addFile({
      ...file,
      sending: true
    }))

    return uploadFile(actualFile, {
      onUploadProgress: (evt) => {
        if(evt.loaded && evt.total) {
          const progress = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100

          dispatch(setFileProgress(file.id, progress))
        }
      }
    })
    .then((fileUrl) => {
      dispatch(setFileSent(file.id))
      dispatch(setFileUrl(file.id, url))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      dispatch(setFileErrored(file.id))
    })
  }
}
```

**note** : `uploadFile` is a helper of mine, wrapping an axios promise.
The first parameter is a `File` descriptor, the second one is an axios options object.

Which I believe should work..

But now I'm struggling with some design questions :

- Is that the correct way to do it ? I mean:

  - this is full of impurities, but ajax queries by nature are Impure..
  - I'm completely loosing the `File` descriptor reference, thus disallowing any chance to access it later (eg. for `preview`). Where would I store it ? I find this so bad to store it in the store, mainly because we can't purely update a `File` descriptor with ES6 stuff, and thus we need to mutate it
- Axios provide a neat `CancelToken` stuff, which I can pass to my options. I've been using it before in React, but switching to redux, the same question come to me : if I define a `cancelToken` in `uploadFile()`, where do I store it, so I can access it inside a further, say, `cancelFileUpload(fileId)` thunk action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reducer side, I think your actions are good (+1 on spread/rest). But the code structure could look a bit better by using some "update-in" libraries like [`simple-update-in`](https://npmjs.com/package/simple-update-in). It helps you to eliminate some `filter()` calls.

On the action design, I guess you are building an upload queue, so you need to have `QUEUE`/`SEND_PENDING`/`SEND_PROGRESS`/`SEND_REJECTED`/`SEND_FULFILLED` (I rephrased them with [`redux-promise-middleware`](https://npmjs.com/package/redux-promise-middleware) naming approach for clarity.) Nothing you can escape here.

On the action factory, because Promise doesn't have a progress event, so it looks a bit clunky right now. You can try implement using `redux-saga`. The code looks just a tiny bit cleaner. But handling multiple events become a breeze. But there is a learning curve there. The code should looks similar below. Focus on the while-loop below, and also look at the cancel handling (thru `CANCEL` action).

```
import { call, put, race, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import EventAsPromise from 'event-as-promise';

yield takeEvery('QUEUE', function* (action) {
  yield put({ type: 'SEND_PENDING' });

  const { file } = action.payload;
  const progress = new EventAsPromise();
  const donePromise = uploadFile(file, progress.eventListener);

  try {
    while (true) {
      // Wait until one of the Promise is resolved/rejected
      const [progress] = yield race([
        // New progress event came in
        call(progress.upcoming),

        // File upload completed promise resolved or rejected
        call(() => donePromise),

        // Someone dispatched 'CANCEL'
        take(action => action.type === 'CANCEL' && action.payload.file === file)
      ]);

      if (progress) {
        // Progress event come first, so process it here
        yield put({ 
          type: 'SEND_PROGRESS', 
          payload: { 
            loaded: progress.loaded,
            total: progress.total
          }
        });
      } else {
        // Either done or cancelled (use your cancel token here)
        // Breaking a while-true loop isn't really looks good, but there aren't any better options here
        break;
      }
    }

    // Here, we assume CANCEL is a kind of fulfillment and do not require retry logic
    yield put({ type: 'SEND_FULFILLED' });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: 'SEND_REJECTED', error: true, payload: err });
  }
});
```

To upload a file, dispatch a `QUEUE` action. To cancel a uploading file, just dispatch a `CANCEL` action.

Since `redux-saga` only accept Promise or action, to convert stream of events into Promise, I introduced [`event-as-promise`](https://npmjs.com/package/event-as-promise) here.

With `redux-saga`, the flow control (progress/done/error/cancel) become very clear and less prone to bugs. In your case, I am using `redux-saga` in a way it behaves like a lifecycle manager for the file upload. Setup and teardown always come in a pair. And you don't need to worry if the teardown calls (done/error/cancel) are not fired properly.

You need to figure out the story about the file descriptor. Try not to put it in the store because it would prevent store to be persisted, which you may want to persist the store across page navigations or app restart. Depends on your scenario, if it is used for retrying upload, you can store it temporarily in the closure inside the saga.

In this example, you can easily extend it into an upload queue which upload file one-by-one. It's not a difficult task if you are proficient with `redux-saga`, should be less than 10 lines of code change. Without `redux-saga`, it will be quite a big task to make it happen.

Comment: Insane answer, but as you mentionned, there is a learning curve there :P I need time to check this great stuff out.

In the meantime, would you answer that : is that code generator-bound, or is this promise - translatable ? I'm pretty noob with generators, and much more a promise guy, maybe that could straigthen a little the learning curve :X

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about "generator-bound" and "promise-translatable"? Redux saga use generators to maintain a "workflow". And there is an escape hatch from generator to Promise, by using `redux-saga/effects/call` function. But there is no escape hatch for event, thus we need to convert event to promise.

Comment: I meant the code you provided is fully generator based. I digged a little into redux-saga, and trying to understand those generators things.
I was wondering if one **has** to use generators, or is this achievable through promises only

Comment: One has to use generator. I also think about turning everything into Promise when I start on redux-saga, I thought it was legacy issue. But in fact, redux-saga use generator to "save the workflow" using closure. So redux-saga can always "continue where it left". Pretty clever trick. But the downside: you can't persist the workflow, or restore the workflow.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I'm accepting this, even if redux-saga is not the way I went.
Way too cryptic syntax to me, leading to less maintenability. I went with redux-logic for now, and thinking about going with rematch or something simpler for side effects, logic and everything